# Tic Tac Toe in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I have created Tic Tac Toe game using plain JavaScript. Can any javascript expert review it and let me know whether the way I have written JavaScript code that is right (preferable)?

I am unsure that I wrote the `OnLoad` function in a preferable way. I wanted wrap all my code in an immediate invoking function but that didn't work out well.

I just want to improve my JavaScript coding knowledge. I want to write JS code more professional way.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vBJhH)

**HTML**

```html
<html>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ticTac.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ticTac.js"></script>       
</head>
<body onload="fnLoad()">
        <div class="container">
                <div>
                        <select id="grid">
                        </select>
                        <button name="NewGame" class="newGame" value="Start a New Game" onClick="fnNewGame()">Start a New Game</button>
                </div>
                <div class="minContainer">
                        <table class="row" id="game"></table>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
var turn = 'X';
var score = {
    'X': 0,
    'O': 0
};
var gridValue = 0;

function fnLoad() {
    var select = document.getElementById("grid");
    for (i = 3; i <= 100; i += 1) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + ' X ' + i, i);
    }

    addEvent(document.getElementById("game"), "click", fnChoose);

    fnNewGame();
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {

    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}

function fnChoose(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "TD") {
        var targetElement = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        var prevTurn;
        if ((targetElement.className).indexOf("disabled") == -1) {
            targetElement.innerHTML = turn;
            targetElement.classList.add('disabled');
            targetElement.classList.add(turn);
            score[turn] += 1;
            prevTurn = turn;
            turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
            if (fndecide(targetElement, prevTurn)) {
                alert(prevTurn + ' has won the game');
                fnNewGame();
            } else if ((score['X'] + score['O']) == (gridValue * gridValue)) {
                alert('Draw!');
                fnNewGame();
            }
        }
    }
}

function fndecide(targetElement, prevTurn) {
    var UL = document.getElementById('game');
    var elements, i, j, cnt;
    if (score[prevTurn] >= gridValue) {
        var classes = targetElement.className.split(/\s+/);
        for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
            cnt = 0;
            if (classes[i].indexOf('row') !== -1 || classes[i].indexOf('col') !== -1 || classes[i].indexOf('dia') !== -1) {
                elements = UL.getElementsByClassName(classes[i]);
                for (j = 0; j < elements.length; j += 1) {
                    if (elements[j].innerHTML == prevTurn) {
                        cnt += 1;
                    }
                }
                if (cnt == gridValue) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function fnNewGame() {
    var gameUL = document.getElementById("game");
    if (gameUL.innerHTML !== '') {
        gameUL.innerHTML = null;
        score = {
            'X': 0,
            'O': 0
        };
        turn = 'X';
        gridValue = 0;
    }
    var select = document.getElementById("grid");
    gridValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var i, j, li, k = 0,
        classLists;
    var gridAdd = +gridValue + 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= gridValue; i += 1) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j = 1; j <= gridValue; j += 1) {
            k += 1;
            li = document.createElement('td');
            li.setAttribute("id", 'li' + k);

            classLists = 'td row' + i + ' col' + j;

            if (i === j) {
                classLists = 'td row' + i + ' col' + j + ' dia0';
            }

            if ((i + j) === gridAdd) {
                classLists = 'td row' + i + ' col' + j + ' dia1';
            }

            if (!isEven(gridValue) && (Math.round(gridValue / 2) === i && Math.round(gridValue / 2) === j))
                classLists = 'td row' + i + ' col' + j + ' dia0 dia1';

            li.className = classLists;
            tr.appendChild(li);

        }
        gameUL.appendChild(tr);
    }
}


function isEven(value) {
    if (value % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**CSS**

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
}


.minContainer {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.td {
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#ccc;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    min-width: 32px;
    max-width: 32px;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.X{
    background-color: #FF8362;    
}

.O{
    background-color: #BB7365;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm not a JavaScript expert and you might want to wait for one. But here are a few things that stand out.

#### Variable declaration

You forgot to declare your loop variables. Instead of:

> ```
> for (i = 3; i <= 100; i += 1) {
>     // ... 
> }
> ```

You should write like this:

```
for (var i = 3; i <= 100; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

That is, declare the variable with `var i`. You should correct this in all your loops. And a `tr` variable in `fnNewGame`, should have been:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
```

Also, it's customary to write `++i` or `i++` instead of `i += 1`.

#### Simplify `isEven`

There's no need to wrap a boolean expression in an `if-else` just to return a boolean:

> ```
> function isEven(value) {
>     if (value % 2 == 0)
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> }
> ```

You can use the result of a boolean expression directly:

```
function isEven(value) {
    return value % 2 == 0;
}
```

#### Simplify notation

You don't have to, but you can write some expressions in a simpler way:

> ```
> var score = {
>     'X': 0,
>     'O': 0
> };
> ```

You can omit the quoting of the key names and write simpler as:

```
var score = {
    X: 0,
    O: 0
};
```

And you can access `score.X` and `score.O` instead of `score['X']` and `score['O']`.

#### Unused variables

Remove unused variables, for example this:

> ```
> var option = document.createElement('option');
> ```

#### Check yourself

To avoid common mistakes, simply copy-paste your code on http://jshint.com/ and fix the warnings it detects.

Comment: Nice thing about CR is that we don't need to read the question to learn from the answers :D

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of points in addition to the answer of [@janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60877/49695)

### JavaScript

**Naming**

Try to be consistend in your naming:

- use camelCase everywhere (`fndecide` should be `fnDecide`, `UL` should be `ul`).
- if you want to use hungarian notation, use it everywhere (`isEven` then should be `fnIsEven`).

Also, some names could be better:

- `fndecide` is not a very good name. Try to find a more descriptive name (eg `fnIsWin`, `fnXInARow`, etc).
- `score` is a confusing name. I would expect that this holds how often each player won, but instead it holds how many fields a player owns in this round.
- `gridValue` is also not very descriptive, `gridDimensions` or similar would be better.

**Variable declaration**

In addition to what [@janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60877/49695) said, variables should be defined where they are used. In `fndecide` you declare a lot of them at the beginning of the function: `var elements, i, j, cnt;` (you do the same in `fnNewGame`).

**prevTurn**

If you move `turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";` to the end of the `fnChoose` function, then you don't need to save it in the temporary `prevTurn` variable, thus getting rid of that variable and making the code more readable.

**Curly Braces**

I think that not using curly braces around one-line if statements is bad and can easily lead to bugs. Others disagree, but I think that it should at least be handled consistently. You use them everywhere except in one place, which is unexpected.

**`===` vs `==`**

Sometimes you use `===` and sometimes `==`, but there doesn't seem to be a good reason for your choice. I would consistently use `===`, except for when you need `==` (see this question for the [difference between the JavaScript equals operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)).

**onload**

> I am unsure that I wrote the OnLoad function in a preferable way.

<strike>As you are using jQuery, you can just use [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)</strike> (Thinking about a different OP... )

Your onload is fine. The alternative would be: [`window.onload=function(){<your code>};`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload).

### CSS

I'm not that great with CSS, but you definitely shouldn't have `</style>` in an CSS file.

Also, `appearance:none;`: [`none` is not a valid value for `appearance`)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp)

### HTML

`title` should be inside `head`, not before.

You have a couple more smaller errors in your HTML, you can check it with the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)